# How to put in checkboxes values into a session variable without any button clicks?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

lets say i have a code pretty similar like this

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="account1" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="account2" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="account3" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="account4" value="4">


  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Now i want to store the value of the checkbox in a php session once the user checked the boxes without clicking the submit/delete button. I plan to use jquery/ajax for this but i still cant quite wrap my head around it since im very new to ajax or jquery.

To add more detail, the process is like this..
the user can select any account he wants he checked. lets say he checked an account on page 1. he then went to another page(pagination) and then went back to page 1, the checked boxes would still be checked.

Comment: Consider using a click event? `anInput.addEventListener('click', dostuff)`

Comment: *then went back to page 1* - how exactly is the paging handled?  If it's server-side then you'll need to send it to the server.  If it's client-side, then the client-side should handle it.

Comment: i dont quite understand that but i used php queries for the pagination.
as for click event, like i said im very-very new for jquery/ajax/javascript. i do know what it does but i just dont know how javascript/ajax/jquery things connects to a php session

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="account2" value="2" checked>`... ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you're loading the data from the backend. Add an event listener as described in the first comment and send status change to the backend with [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). On page change, you have to set the status according to the data from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onchange` event listener for this.

Live example [here](https://koding-khurram.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow/questions/70293736/).

**index.php**

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="account1" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="account2" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="account3" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="account4" value="4">


    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
  </form>

  <br/><strong>You can see the checkbox values in session below...</strong>
  <div id="newDiv">
  </div>

  <script>
  $('*[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function(){
    var check = 0;
    if(this.checked == true) check = 1;
    var value = this.value;
    $.post("session.php", { box : value, check : check }, function(data, status){
      if(status == "success"){
        $('#newDiv').load("values.php");
      }
    })
  })
  </script>
```

**session.php**

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['box'])){
  //Separate session variable for each checkbox.
  $checkbox = "checkBox".$_POST['box'];
  $_SESSION[$checkbox] = $_POST['check'];
}
?>
```

**values.php**

```
<?
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! i followed the jquery but i did a little tweak for the session.php and values.php. i put them in array with the accountid and the check boolean as the key inside the numerical keys. It really helped me thanks again!